# Continuous rotation of image on button click using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want that the image gets rotated after every 1 sec.I have used following code but it doesn't work.
My code is :-

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.rotated-image 
{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
 transform: rotate(2deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section id="middle">

<img id="image" src="1.png" >   
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</section>
<script>

function myFunction() 
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.setAttribute("class", "rotated-image");
setTimeout("myFunction()",1000);    

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you check my answer? try it once

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with pure CSS. Try this:

```
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes animate-rotate{
    from {
         -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
         -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-keyframes animate-rotate{
    from {
         -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
         -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.rotated-image 
{
    -webkit-animation: animate-rotate 180s infinite;
    animation: animate-rotate 180s infinite;
}
</style>


function myFunction() 
{
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.setAttribute("class", "rotated-image"); 
}
```

Comment: I edited it to 180s. The OP wanted 2 deg per 1 sec, so 360 deg need to have duration of 180s. Anyway adjusting the duration of the animation should be pretty straightforward now :)

Comment: Now I want to stop the rotation on click of another button.Then what should I do?

Comment: Just remove the class. document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("class", ""); or document.getElementById("image").removeAttribute("class");

Comment: I have written "var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.removeAttribute("class", "rotated-image"); " in body of another function and I have called this function on click of another button.But the image is still rotating even after clicking this button.

Comment: @user3298056 have you check my answer

Comment: the removeAttribute method is called with only one parameter, the attribute name, in this example: 'class'. I just tried, it works. However if you need it to stop rotating at the current rotating angle you are better off with a javascript solution, i.e. Satish's.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
var deg = 2; // starting
var rotation_diff = 30; // you can change it to 2 if you want to rotate 2 deg in each second

function myFunction() 
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");

img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.transform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.msTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.OTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";

setTimeout("myFunction()",1000);    
deg = deg + rotation_diff;
}
```

see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ThL2/)

**UPDATE 2:**

For START and STOP

HTML

```
<img id="image" src="http://static.kuikr.com/images/quikr_logo_f3.png" >   
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var deg = 2; // starting
var rotation_diff = 30;

var rotation;

function start()
{
    rotation=1;    
    myFunction();
}

function stop()
{
    rotation=0;    
}

function myFunction() 
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");

img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.transform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.msTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.OTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";

    if(rotation==1) {

        setTimeout("myFunction()",1000);   } 
deg = deg + rotation_diff;
}
```

see [**UPDATE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ThL2/1/)

Comment: In rotate("+deg+"deg),why deg is used twice?

Comment: its first `deg` is a variable which is increment each time when `myFunction`  is call and second one is string(css postfix for rotation). have you seen the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ss = 2;


    function myFunction() {

        ss = ss + 1;
        $("#image").css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + ss + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + ss + 'deg)'
        });
        setTimeout("myFunction()", 1000);
    }
```